# Can I embed PowerPoint online in a web page while blocking download and PP Online access?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, embedding

We have a requirement to share PowerPoint presentations with others within our company. I'd like to discourage people from downloading them, because they change frequently and we want people to refer to the latest version. Microsoft offers a very useful ability to embed PowerPoint Online files in a web page with embed code, but that code offers the ability to save a copy in either PDF or PPTX format. There's no obvious way to block that. I'm wondering anyone here can suggest a **non-obvious** way ....

Thanks.

Comment: This function will depend on a web server that offers these functions. Security and function as you describe it outside the capabilities of the file or format itself.

Comment: I was looking for functionality like that in, oh, node.js that lets you decide which on-screen controls are present. I can turn off, say, the progress bar in the video player. I was hoping that MS allowed that in the JS that embeds their PowerPoints. I'm well aware of how the PPTX file format works, but the "server" in this case is the PowerPoint Online server, which is (of course) not fully documented in any obvious place.

Comment: Then this question is off topic because it is about a web server.  It is also too broad as it is worded because you're asking "can I..." and the answer to that is either "yes" or "no", possibly "maybe". You may find answers on our Web Apps or Enterprise Systems (if you're IT) sister sites. Whichever of these sites you try, I highly recommend you rephrase your question to focus not one whether this is possible, but by clearly asking HOW to accomplish such a thing.

Comment: @CarlF In case it helps, I'm involved in a discussion of just this topic with several of the MS PPT MVPs, nearly all of whom need this capability but there's no known solution. Please do visit powerpoint.uservoice.com, search for posts about this issue and add your vote. It's one of the best ways of making sure that MS developers get the word.  One outside possibility:  use one of the various available converters to turn your presentation into HTML and post that for your users.